# how to use the refreshAccessToken method to generate a new accesstoken in google-api-nodejs-client

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I see that [this pull request](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/commit/e35cf43817b332821619a3429702d999d36758a2) adds a method to refresh the access token using a saved refresh token. It is not clear to me how to use it. I have saved the tokens (including the refresh token) from the original getToken request and am now retrieving the token from the Database in a new session. How do I set the credentials on OAuth2Client so that I can call refreshAccessToken and get a new accesstoken?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had missed the [paragraph on setting credentials on the github readme](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#making-authenticated-requests), so here is some sample code in case anybody else needs it.

```
var googleOauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(googleClientId,googleClientSecret, googleCallbackUrl);
googleOauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: saved_refresh_token
});
googleOauth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function(err, tokens){
  response.send({
    access_token: tokens.access_token
  });
});
```

Comment: you should choose your answer as the answer!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response but, could you expand it a little bit? I can't see where response  is defined. Is googleCallBackUrl mandatory? This is very hard for me to understand. If you post a complete example I will be very grateful.

Comment: As a note for others, it seems `refreshAccessToken` is deprecated. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: I cloned the repo and searched, and found this in a CHANGELOG: _Note: `refreshAccessToken` is no longer deprecated._

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as I haven't used this library. But it looks to me like you simply call `myOAuth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function(err, newCredentials){})`, where you have already instantiated the `OAuth2Client` object with the old token. (dunno how you do that but it might be as simple as instantiating the object then `myOauth2Client.credentials.refresh_token = 'foobar'`.) And if there's no error, it'll modify the `OAuth2Client.credentials` object and additionally pass the credentials object to the callback.