# Nodejs Google OAuth API refreshaccesstoken()

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

I am storing the access_token and refresh_token generated into the database.
When the access_token expires I need to refresh the access token using refresh_token. This I have achieved by following method:

```
oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function (err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
console.log("Error in refreshing token: " + err);
            return;
        }
        if (tokens) {
            console.log("tokens:- ", tokens);
        }
    });
```

But the issue here is that using Webstorm as an IDE it is showing that the method "refreshaccesstoken" is deprecated.
Can anyone help me in this situation !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing any of the credentials to given. please re-examine the code. You can go through the [link](
[how to use the refreshAccessToken method to generate a new accesstoken in google-api-nodejs-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947663/how-to-use-the-refreshaccesstoken-method-to-generate-a-new-accesstoken-in-google)). Also you can check in [git](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#manually-refreshing-access-token)